# how to get the rows if textbox value has changed inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: Gridview that contains textboxes]

After editing the textbox values inside this gridview, i need to get the rows (only edited rows) in button click event (button placed outside the gridview).

Answer (score 0):

Add event listener on the gridview to grab the selected items value on change, and add them to an array. Loop through to use the data.

Comment: can u pls give any example for this !